# ExpectedException Attribute Usage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, expected-exception

I am trying to work with the `ExpectedException` attribute in a `C# UnitTest`, but I am having issues getting it to work with my particular `Exception`. Here's what I got:

**NOTE:** I wrapped asterisks around the line that is giving me the trouble.

```
    [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
    public void TestSetCellContentsTwo()
    {
        // Create a new Spreadsheet instance for this test:
        SpreadSheet = new Spreadsheet();

        // If name is null then an InvalidNameException should be thrown. Assert that the correct 
        // exception was thrown.
        ReturnVal = SpreadSheet.SetCellContents(null, "String Text");
        **Assert.IsTrue(ReturnVal is InvalidNameException);**

        // If text is null then an ArgumentNullException should be thrown. Assert that the correct
        // exception was thrown.
        ReturnVal = SpreadSheet.SetCellContents("A1", (String) null);
        Assert.IsTrue(ReturnVal is ArgumentNullException);

        // If name is invalid then an InvalidNameException should be thrown. Assert that the correct 
        // exception was thrown.
        {
            ReturnVal = SpreadSheet.SetCellContents("25", "String Text");
            Assert.IsTrue(ReturnVal is InvalidNameException);

            ReturnVal = SpreadSheet.SetCellContents("2x", "String Text");
            Assert.IsTrue(ReturnVal is InvalidNameException);

            ReturnVal = SpreadSheet.SetCellContents("&", "String Text");
            Assert.IsTrue(ReturnVal is InvalidNameException);
        }
    }
```

I have the `ExpectedException` catching the base type `Exception`. Shouldn't this take care of it? I have tried using `AttributeUsage`, but it wasn't helping either. I know I can wrap it in a try/catch block, but I'd like to see if I can figure this style out.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It will fail unless the type of exception is exactly the type you've specified in the attribute 
e.g

PASS:-

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(System.DivideByZeroException))]
    public void DivideTest()
    {
        int numerator = 4;
        int denominator = 0;
        int actual = numerator / denominator;
    }
```

FAIL:-

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(System.Exception))]
    public void DivideTest()
    {
        int numerator = 4;
        int denominator = 0;
        int actual = numerator / denominator;
    }
```

However this will pass ...

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(System.Exception), AllowDerivedTypes=true)]
    public void DivideTest()
    {
        int numerator = 4;
        int denominator = 0;
        int actual = numerator / denominator;
    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for the explanation. Here's to some easy rep, cheers!

Comment: I wouldn't encourage 

    [TestMethod()]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(System.Exception), AllowDerivedTypes=true)]

For the same reason I wouldn't encourage 
...
catch(Exception ex) {....

Comment: Don't we need a try/catch around the expected offending code to catch the expected exception?

Comment: @SuLlewellyn catching the exception without rethrowing would cause the test to fail when the ExpectedExceptionAttribute is applied.